# NavigationItemSelectedListener cannot triggered when i clicked the item inside

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have navigation drawer, and it have items on it. but when I click,nothing happens. what's wrong with this code?

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navi_1:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(BaseOrderActivity.this,BaseOrderActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("dataDealerCode",dataorderCode);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navi_2:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(BaseOrderActivity.this,MappingProductRecycler.class);
                        intent2.putExtra("dataDealerCode",dataorderCode);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        finish();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navi_3:
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(BaseOrderActivity.this,UpdateProductActivity.class);
                        intent3.putExtra("dataDealerCode",dataorderCode);
                        startActivity(intent3);
                        finish();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navi_4:
                        return true;
                }
                //drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

When I put breakpoint at NavigationItemSelected, it does not stop at breakpoint, so I cannot start the other activity base on my selected . why?

this is my Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".BaseOrderActivity"
         />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseOrderActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_y="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

what wrong with my Layout?

Comment: Try to put end of your onNavigationItemSelected , DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        invalidateOptionsMenu();

        return true;

Comment: can you show us your xml for navigation drawer and also its menu items ?

Comment: @zephyr i already put that code to end of my onNavigationSelected but ,it nothing change.

Comment: Can you tell us, is there Specific reason for using Activity? generally Use fragments for NavigationDrawer. I am not saying you can't use Activity. And u are also closing current activity by finish(); statements. When you press back, it will go to error or exception. So Handle that wisely.

Comment: See my updated post.. and follow those steps.. It will help you..

Comment: Post your layout code, it's possible something is wrong there

Comment: updated my layout @SumitJha

Comment: update my layout @jL4

Comment: @j.lo Please see edits in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that your navigation item selection doesn't seem to work, here are the possible trouble shooting steps:

1. Check if the navigation view is properly initialized.

   ```
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation); //navigation is the id of the xml for your navigation view.
   ```
2. Check the ids in your switch case.  `R.id.navi_1:` etc. (`navi_1, etc.`) are indeed valid.

Edit:

You should have only 2 view (child) in your drawer layout. The first child is the one that will be shown when the drawer is CLOSED and the second when the drawer is OPEN.

See the sample xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    // this is the main screen, shown when the drawer is CLOSED
    // 1st VIEW
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_home_users"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    // This view is shown when drawer is OPEN
    // 2nd View
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_layout"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Snackbar.Message"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

EDIT 2:
In your case, you can make the relative layout as the first view.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".BaseOrderActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_y="50dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead

```
      navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        Intent intent;
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navi_1:
                    intent= new Intent(BaseOrderActivity.this,BaseOrderActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("dataDealerCode",dataorderCode);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    break;
                case R.id.navi_2:
                    intent = new Intent(BaseOrderActivity.this,MappingProductRecycler.class);
                    intent.putExtra("dataDealerCode",dataorderCode);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    break;
                case R.id.navi_3:
                    intent = new Intent(BaseOrderActivity.this,UpdateProductActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("dataDealerCode",dataorderCode);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    break;
                case R.id.navi_4:
                    break;
            }
            //drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain how is this gonna solve the issue ? Anyway the switch case is gonna break and ``true`` is returned.

Comment: Then problem is not with switch case right.is it going inside case?

Comment: Syntactically there is no difference between your code and the OP's snippet.

Comment: op snippet?what?post your xml also once..we can figure the problem

Comment: OP stands for original poster. The one who has posted this question.

Comment: j.lo post your xml

Answer (score 0):

When you have to use `switch` statement should use `break` in your every `case`. but now your using **return** in inside case block

you should follow this steps it will work...

1. Implement the navigationView linstner in your `BaseOrderActivity` like `BaseOrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity
       implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`
2. Create your menu in your menu.xml
3. Initialize you NavigationView in `Oncreate`

   ```
   NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
   navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
   ```
4. Finally use this override methods

   ```
     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
          return true;
     }

     @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
       @Override
       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
           // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
           int id = item.getItemId();
           Intent intent = null;
           switch (id) {
               case R.id.navi_1:
                   intent = new Intent(this,BaseOrderActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra("dataDealerCode",dataorderCode);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   break;
               case R.id.navi_2:
                   intent = new Intent(this,MappingProductRecycler.class);
                   intent.putExtra("dataDealerCode",dataorderCode);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   break;
           }
           DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
           drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
           return true;
       }
   ```

**Note: Once you use finish then your current Activity/Context will getting Stop/Terminate, So If you use safe way**

Hope it will help you..

Comment: its not about the "break", even i put breakpoints and debug at onNavigationItemSelected , the debug cannot be there , just like my selected is not triggered

Comment: thanks, i updated my layout , maybe that layout causing this problem @Raja

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead

```
 int ids=menuItem.getItemId();
 switch (ids) {
    case R.id.itemID:
          //Your Code
         break
    default:
         break;
 }
 drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
 return true;
```